Can i use an outbound ip address as a static ip for an app service?
i have an app service in Azure , at the moment there are about 20 outbound ip addresses and client have to whitelist all these ip addresses. I want to make the app have a static ip address so i configured a public ip in azure and associated it to the app.
But when i create the new publicip address can i use one of the existing outbound ip addresses as the public ip address instead of making the customers have to whitelist another ip ?
or does azure automatically assign you a new one ?
i was expecting to be able to set an existing outbound ip as a public ip

Not sure if this is what you're looking for? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/ip-services/custom-ip-address-prefix

To get a dedicated static outbound IP address, you need to integrate your App Service with an Azure VNet and use an Azure NAT Gateway

When i create the public ip , does azure auto allocate one or can i change it to be one of the outbound ip addresses ? In otherwords can I pick my own ip address ? –

By default, Azure App Services allocates outbound IP addresses dynamically. This means the IP address your app uses to connect to external services can change over time.
You can view the current outbound IPs in the Azure portal or through Azure CLI.
az webapp show --resource-group <group_name> --name <app_name> --query possibleOutboundIpAddresses --output tsv

You can however integrate your app with a Vnet and configure a NAT Gateway to have a single fixed outbound IP. This is one of the common uses of NAT Gateways.
Azure firewall also provides SNAT capability, which can be used to associate a static outbound IP with your applications.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-inbound-outbound-ips#find-outbound-ips

I get all that , but when i create the public ip , does azure auto allocate one or can i change it to be one of the outbound ip addresses ?

You need to create a static public IP and attach it to your NAT Gateway. It becomes your outbound IP address if you configure your VNet and App Services correctly.

Welcome Kristen .
Public IP addresses are only for inbound connections to a Azure resources, so they wouldn't help you in your quest to restrict the IP address used by outbound connections from an App Service.
Outbound connections will always originate from a range of source IPs. As your App Service scales out to multiple instances then different instances will issue outbound requests from different source IP addresses.

So in other words I simply  cant allocate my own ip address is that correct ?

See Vikyol's excellent answer re using a virtual network and Azure NAT Gateway integration.

I have seen that but what im asking is that under the Public IP when i create it , it does not give me an option to select the IP address. So in short I cant allocate my own IP address ? Is that right ?
